# stderr:Warning: Error in poppler_pdf_data: Getting font data requires poppler >= 0.89. You have 0.73.0

Tags: r

I am using R 3.6.2 and have latest pdftools 3.2.1 version, I am not sure whatever I try i keep getting `stderr:Warning: Error in poppler_pdf_data: Getting font data requires poppler >= 0.89. You have 0.73.0 ..`
Not sure from where poppler is getting picked? I even tried to manually copy paste the pdftools library , still same result.
Can some please please advise.

Comment: What do you get when you run `packageVersion("poppler")`?

Comment: > packageVersion("poppler")
Error in packageVersion("poppler") : there is no package called 'poppler'
> packageVersion("pdftools")
[1] '3.2.1'

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want to know > library("pdftools")
Using poppler version 0.73.0
>

Comment: Whatever I do , its always same ..

Comment: I think you have to install `poppler` package manually. Here you have a link where you can download the latest version (you can not install from CRAN): https://poppler.freedesktop.org/

Comment: Well. Then why in R-Studio it works ? which is V 4.2 ? and I have tried copying pdftools libraries from there  as well.. secomd I am not understanding where to keep poppler ?